# Security issues about parameters in the URL that will be used as parameters of stored procedures

Tags: sql, security

There is a web service and it exposes a function named A().
Users can make a request to the method with a parameter.
And the parameter is used as an input of a stored procedure.

For example, An User makes a request with the url:

- localhost/WS?Code=Hello

And the parameter is used in a stored procedure like this:

- SELECT * FROM **@Code**

However, The code has a security hole because the method A() doesn't filter any dangerous characters in the Code variable. It must sanitize the input.

In that case, how can I sanitize the input? I currently just remove some characters, but I'm not sure if the code really removes any SQL Injection possibility.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to sanitize the input; use a parameterized query instead.

For example, assuming C#:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Code = @Code", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", code);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the role of Request.QueryString? It doesn't remove any harmful characteres. Do I miss something?

Comment: @SungamYang: No, `Request.QueryString` doesn't remove any "harmful" characters. It was just an example of retrieving the value passed by the user. The point is to use a parameterized query, which is not susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the information and your time. However, I think that I have to remove special characters that affects the SQL statement.

Comment: @SungamYang: If you use a parameterized query, there are *no* "special" characters. Data in a parameter *cannot* be interpreted as part of the query.

Comment: (It may be worth validing the input *as well*, to get rid of any characters you don't expect to be used - for example control characters. But this is nothing to do with SQL injection, for which the proper response is parameterised queries.)